# Dojo query descendants?

Tags: javascript, dojo

My code:

```
var parent = document.createElement('div');
var pen = document.createElement('div');
var dog = document.createElement('div');
dog.className = "dog";
pen.appendChild(dog);
parent.appendChild(pen);
dojo.query("> *", parent).forEach( function(node){
    if(node.className == "dog")alert('bark');
});
dojo.query("> .dog", parent).forEach( function(node){
    alert('bark');
});
```

I'm getting no alert "bark"s.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the HTML? Also, I'd use `dojo.hasClass` instead of `className`

Comment: I use domClass.contains normally, but in this case there's no difference.  Also there is no HTML.

Comment: I'd count the generated dom as HTML, but I suppose you're right. As for `domClass`, I guess I assume if there's no `require/define` at the top of the page, then the person is using an older version of Dojo. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is that the generated html doesn't match the selector:

```
<div title="parent">
    <div title="pen">
        <div class="dog">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because `> *` will only match `pen` and `> .dog` won't match. You could change these to:

```
var parent = document.createElement('div');
var pen = document.createElement('div');
var dog = document.createElement('div');
dog.className = "dog";
pen.appendChild(dog);
parent.appendChild(pen);
dojo.query("> * > *", parent).forEach(function (node) {
    if (node.className == "dog") {
        alert('bark');
    }
});
dojo.query("> * > .dog", parent).forEach(function (node) {
    alert('bark');
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pTqmL/

**Edit**

Or if it just needs to be inside of `parent`:

```
dojo.query("*", parent).forEach(function (node) {
    if (node.className == "dog") {
        alert('bark');
    }
});
dojo.query(".dog", parent).forEach(function (node) {
    alert('bark');
});
```

Based on your comment, I think the core thing you might be overlooking/unaware of is that query is scoped inside of parent.

Comment: there's no string for query function which goes as deep as possible to fetch all the descendants? Or do we have to do "> " manually for each layer of descendants?

Comment: You can exclude the > too. The query will only look inside of parent.